# Using (“Almost”, “Nearly”, etc. + {negative statements: “no” / “nobody” / “nothing” / “never”}

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Please have a look on my examples below and let me know what would be your pick(s) out of all my listed adverbs and why?

**Example #1:**

> - Yesterday we went to the Chelsea Flower Show. As you warned us, we expected to face quite a few people but __________ nobody was there.

a. [almost](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/almost) 
b. [nearly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/nearly) 
c. [practically](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/practically) 
d. [roughly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/roughly) 
e. [approximately](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/approximately)

**Example #2:**

> A) Have you ever heard of the HARP project?
>   B) Not, what does it stand for?!
>   A) It is the acronym for High-Altitude Research Project.
>   B) I know __________ nothing about it. But I’m interested to know more.

a. [almost](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/almost) 
b. [nearly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/nearly) 
c. [practically](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/practically) 
d. [roughly](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/roughly) 
e. [approximately](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/approximately)

In all examples above, I believe that the first three choices mean equally the same think (just the choice “c” as dictionaries have mentioned is a bit informal sounding.) Nevertheless, I’m not quite sure if the other options (“d” and “e”) work properly or not. I was wondering if you could give me a hand to find out which choice works correctly in each example and which one doesn’t?

Comment: You can eliminate d) and e) from your multiple choice exam question.

Answer (score 1):

- [‘His suitcase finally turned up almost a month later, but it **was practically empty**.’](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/practically)
- [‘The walk will cover a distance of four miles **taking approximately** two hours to complete.’](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/approximately)
- [‘I think all writers, **roughly speaking**, are in the education business.’](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/roughly)

Have a look at those examples and others and then you should be able to see which adverbs fit better (there can be more than one).

<sub>(Answer transcribed from user comments}</sub>